# Accessing static member variable in a static method in class

Tags: c++, static

I have a program in which I wrote a class as follows:

**.h File**

```
typedef map<string, int> stringMap;
class SampleClass{
public:
    void setup();
    void update();
    void draw();
private:
    static stringMap _someMap;
    static stringMap someMapInitializer();
};
```

**.cpp file**

```
//Initializer for static var
stringMap SampleClass::_someMap = someMapInitializer();

stringMap SampleClass::someMapInitializer(){
    _someMap["something"] = 1;
    return _someMap;
}
```

But on doing the above, I start getting "Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error on running the program (compiles fine though)

The above function is changed to the following:

```
stringMap SampleClass::someMapIntializer(){
    map<string, int> m;
    m["somehting"] = 1;
    return m;
}
```

works fine. What is wrong with the first case? Can't I access static member variables in a static function?

Comment: You mention "static var" in your comment, but neither _someMap nor _someMapInitializer() are declared static.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti : Thanks for pointing out. I typed the code in the text box myself and didn't copy paste. Corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, you try to access the object (_someMap) that you are supposed to be initializing. _someMap is not yet initialized there.

Comment: Thanks. That's kinda careless on my part. I ahve another short follow-up query though about initializer. When are the static members initialized? Since I can access the public static variables/members directly in the `main.cpp` without even creating an object/initializing my class, when are these actually initialized by the compiler before the main program starts?

Comment: @user1240679 I think static members are initialized when the class is loaded into memory. For all intensive purposes, you can assume that this is when the program starts, just before `main` is run. Dynamic class loading (the exception to the `"when the program starts"` rule) is a rather advanced concept, probably no need to worry about that now.

Answer (score 1):

C++ guarantees the object `_someMap` with static storage duration will be initialized before any other function in the same *.cpp file is called as a (direct or indirect) result of statements in `main`.

But the process of initializing `_someMap` involves calling the function `_someMapInitializer()`.  If that function returns, `_someMap` will be created using a move constructor or copy constructor, passed the returned value.  But `_someMapInitializer()` then attempts to call a member function on the object `_someMap`, which is not yet constructed.  Undefined Behavior.

For a fix, I'd design it more like...

```
class SampleClass {
    //...
private:
    static stringMap& someMap();
    static void someMapInitializer(stringMap&);
};

stringMap& SampleClass::someMap() {
    static bool init_done = false;
    static stringMap the_map;
    if (!init_done) {
        someMapInitializer(the_map);
        init_done = true;
    }
    return the_map;
}

void SampleClass::someMapInitializer(stringMap& the_map) {
    the_map["something"] = 1;
}
```

This is the "Construct On First Use" idiom.

Now that the only way to get at the map is to call function `someMap()`, there's no way anything could accidentally use it before the `std::map` constructor has been called and the object has been populated with its initial data.